# package jenkins.war including custom plugins

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jenkins

I am trying to package jenkins with customization. Customization here means including few plugins as part of jenkins.war. I am able to add Jenkins provided plugins successfully. But I am facing issue when Custom plugins are added.

Added jenkins.war to webapps folder of tomcat. Started Tomcat and browsed localhost. Selected "Install suggested plugins". I get error saying:
**An error occurred during installation: No such plugin: XXXXXX**

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post full log when error happen. And see https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/08/tutorial-create-a-jenkins-plugin-to-integrate-jenkins-and-nexus-repository/#part3

Comment: @DoNhuVy During the build(generating jenkins.war), there is no error. Jenkins.war file is created successfully. I get the above mentioned error in Jenkins web page.